# How to send hidden parameters when i click on a link in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, hyperlink, action

hi i am using mvc3 and i had a link in my site which currently pass
 one paramtere as shown following

```
<a href="/Call/@Model.id">Link To Call</a>
```

as you can see that i am passing a **id** to my Action , now i
need to pass another parameter but i dont want to change route
 and current situation of link , can i send some something hidden.
 by which my link looks same

> i tried to do this by **`Html.ActionLink`**  but it doesn't work

Please help me . Thanks In Advance

Comment: is that hidden parameters dynamic? or are only placeholders?

Comment: hidden parameters are dynamics

Comment: but i have that value in my model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this, as your hidden fields are dynamic:

add a class to your link:

```
<a class="link-call" href="/Call/@Model.id">Link To Call</a>
```

**Note** that your href should be something like

```
href="@Url.Action("Index", "Call", { id  = @Model.id })"
```

and then, using jQuery, you can easily fillup your link and make that request.

```
$(function() {

    $(".link-call").click(function(evt) {

        evt.preventDefault; // don't jump to /Call/2 automatically

        var url = $(this).attr("href") + "?"; // this will hold /Call/2?

        // append your hidden fields
        url += "hf1=" + $("#hf_001").val();
        url += "&hf2=" + $("#hf_002").val();
        url += "&hf3=" + $("#hf_003").val();

        // make the call
        document.location.href = url;
    });

});
```

your controller might look like this

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, string hf1, string hf2, string hf3)
{

}
```

if your route has the `ID` you can pick up the ID value from the routes and no need to pass it in the method.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve that is to do it semantically => use an HTML `<form>` instead of a link. This way all the input fields values including hidden ones will be automatically sent and you don't need to use any javascript to craft the href of the anchor. So the anchor becomes a submit button of your form.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass it as query string

```
<a href="/Call/@Model.id?parm="+ somevalue>Link To Call</a>
```

Comment: as i said before that i dont want to change my link , i want to send by another way

Comment: "href" mean that you that you are creating a link, and if its link the only way to pass value in a link is to pass it in query string.

Answer (score 0):

Links trigger `Http Get` requests and any data you want to send along with `Get` request is shoved in the query string. If hidden field are dynamic you can append data to query string on click event of hyperlink like

```
$('#linkId').live('click', function(){
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   href += "?param1=" + $("#hidden1").val() + "&param2=" + $("#hidden2").val();
   $(this).attr('href',href);
   return true; 
});
```

The code above will read values from hidden fields and send them along the url. If you don't want this either you have to either change your UI to use form or do ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you are asking in a GET request without editing the uri. I think it is technically possible to use post data in the body of a GET request but not advisable. If you do choose to edit the uri then you will need to edit the parameter list on the action to reflect those changes.

Best to do this wrapped in a form and submit the form.